# MySQL query slow when selecting records with id that is absent from 4 other tables

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I need to select all records from a table containing id's that are not "checked" in four other tables. Here's my query, which works:

```
select id, idDate, idInfo, idChecked from aTable 
where id not in (select id from aSimilarTable1 where idChecked is not null)
and id not in (select id from aSimilarTable2 where idChecked is not null)
and id not in (select id from aSimilarTable3 where idChecked is not null)
and id not in (select id from aSimilarTable4 where idChecked is not null)
```

The tables grow over time, and now this query takes a very long time to run (several minutes, at best). The size of the tables are the following:

aTable - 1000 records

aSimilarTable1, 2, 3, 4 - 50,000 records

I will work on reducing the size of the tables. However, is there a more efficient way to make the above query?

--CLARIFICATION--

Not all id's from aTable may be present in aSimilarTable1,2,3 or 4. I am looking for ids in aTable that are either not present in any aSimilarTable, or if present, are not "checked".

--UPDATE--

Explain plan for the query:

```
id  select_type         table           type    possible_keys   key key_len     ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             aTable              ALL null        null    null        null    796     Using where
5   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  aSimilarTable4      ALL null        null    null        null    21217   Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  aSimilarTable3      ALL null        null    null        null    59077   Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  aSimilarTable2      ALL null        null    null        null    22936   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  aSimilarTable1      ALL null        null    null        null    49734   Using where
```

Comment: What are the structures of the tables? The indexes? The cardinality? Where is our eplain plan?

Comment: @symcbean thanks for comment - attached the explain plan, understand what cardinality is conceptually, but how do I quantify it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`'s.

```
SELECT a.id, a.idDate, a.idInfo, a.idChecked 
FROM aTable a
LEFT JOIN aSimilarTable1 b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN aSimilarTable2 c ON a.id = c.id
LEFT JOIN aSimilarTable3 d ON a.id = d.id
LEFT JOIN aSimilarTable4 e ON a.id = e.id
```

Comment: `WHERE (b.id IS NULL OR NOT b.checked) AND (c.id ...`